# EventTrigger on UserControl 'Loaded' not calling ICommand.Execute

Tags: wpf, xaml, event-binding

I'm trying to execute an ICommand (AsyncRelayCommand) on the loaded event of my UserControl using the [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf) library.

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             ...
             xmlns:Behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
    <Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <Behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
        </Behaviors:EventTrigger>
    </Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
    ...
</UserControl>
```

The command property is called correctly, the Command class is created and it also calls correctly the `CanExecute` method (which returns true).

```
public override ICommand LoadCommand
{
    get { return new AsyncRelayCommand(
              async () => { /*never executed*/ }, 
              () => return !this.IsLoading); // canExecute logic executed (true)
         }
}
```

But it never calls the `Execute` method.

I believe I need somehow tell that I want the UserControl's event, but all examples are looking the same as mine.

Comment: What are you overriding? And why are you creating a new command each time the getter is called?

Comment: @mm8 I'm overriding the base-class (ViewModelBase) property. but you're right, probably should set the command in the constructor and not re-create it on every get. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the design as described, does not adhere to separation of concerns between the user control and an external viewmodel.

I would instead use the `Loaded` event of the `UserControl` and create a specific dependency property on the control which the user will have bound the `ICommand` to when wiring up the control.

**Example**

```
    #region public ICommand LoadCommand
    /// <summary></summary>
    public ICommand LoadCommand
    {
        get => GetValue(LoadCommandProperty) as ICommand;
        set => SetValue(LoadCommandProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the LoadCommand dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LoadCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "LoadCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(MainUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion public ICommand LoadCommand


    private void MainUserControl_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        => LoadCommand?.Execute(null);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. it helped finding the root cause. Problem was that my AsyncRelayCommand was inherited from a RelayCommand. The actual execute method was called on the base class, not my derived class.
re-implementing the command fixed my issue.

Comment: I like thanks that are expressed as an upvote. :-) Glad you worked it out.